# Embed an SWF file in Flex and interact with ExternalInterface functions

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, embed

I use a SWF file that exposes functions and events using ExternalInterface.  Here is an example of an exposed function:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFunction", ExecuteMyFunction);
```

If I embed the file in an HTML page, I can access those functions using JavaScript.

Now, I'm embedding that same SWF file dynamically in a Flex app using the mx:SWFLoader component, something like:

```
<mx:SWFLoader id="myLoader" source="http://localhost/file.swf" autoLoad="true"/>
```

I'm trying to access those exposed functions and events, but I can't find how to interact with those from the Flex app.  I would like to be able to call a function just like from JavaScript, like:

```
myLoader.myFunction();
```

How can I access a function that is exposed by the ExternalInterface within Flex?

Comment: After my research, I found that you can't. I solve this by generating Flash event from the embedded SWF.  Also, I make "public" functions within the SWF.  Then, using the SystemManager, you can call these.  Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to do something like this:

```
var mySubApp:* = (myLoader.content as SystemManager).application;
mySubApp.myFunction();
```

This link has more details:

[Accessing sub-applications from the main application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf619ab-7fe4.html)

Comment: thanks! I also found that a file crossdomain.xml is required and that this code will work only from URL (not in debug/development in Flex).